# (Java) I cannot loop over my arraylist object?

Tags: java, loops, object, arraylist

I'm trying to loop over an ArrayList object but I only get the following:

Name & Education:
com.company.Item@69d9c55

I have no clue why this is happening. I'm using the code provided in the MOOC course that I 'm following online, but am trying to redo this in my own small test project as I want to put what I learned into practice.

Here's the code:
Main

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
        Item item;
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Name plz?");
            String name = scan.nextLine();
            if (name.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }

            System.out.println("Education plz?");
            String education = scan.nextLine();
            if (education.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }

            item = new Item(name, education);
            if (!itemList.contains(item)) {
                itemList.add(item);
            }

        }

        System.out.println("Name & Education: ");
        for(Item detail : itemList) {
            System.out.println(detail);
        }

    }
}
```

and the main Class

```
package com.company;

public class Item {
    String name;
    String education;

    public Item(String name, String education) {
        this.name = name;
        this.education = education;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your for loop you are printing the `detail` object.

```
for(Item detail : itemList) {
    System.out.println(detail);
}

// prints
com.company.Item@69d9c55
```

first part is the package name (think folder sort of) and the random number after the `@` is an hashed value of the object. So basically a sort of short textual representation of the class.

there is two ways of fixing this:

adding getters to the object to fetch the values you want to print:

```
public class Item {
    String name;
    String education;

    public Item(String name, String education) {
        this.name = name;
        this.education = education;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getEducation() {
        return education;
    }
}

// Then in your loop fetch the values
for(Item detail : itemList) {
    System.out.println(detail.getName());
    System.out.println(detail.getEducation());
}
```

or the slightly more advanced version which is overriding the `toString` function in the object. Every object has a function called `toString` which prints per default the object hash. You can customize this by, naming a function `toString` and then annotation the function with `@Override`. Then in that function you can write a custom string that you want printed, when you try to print the object.

```
public class Item {
    String name;
    String education;

    public Item(String name, String education) {
        this.name = name;
        this.education = education;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + ", " + education;
    }
}
```

Comment: actually, it is the value of toString, as inherited from the Object class.

Comment: @Stultuske yes but i didnt want to drag in inheritance into the explanation. That itself is a completly other topic

Comment: @Toerktumlare you are already dragging inheritance in it, by suggesting to override toString. the original prints the name of the class@HexValueOf(hashCode)
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()

Comment: @Stultuske if you are not pleased with my answer, feel free to write your own.

Answer (score -1):

in your **for-loop** while iterating over your **Item list** (maybe you should redefine your ArrayList using polymorphism) you will be getting each time an object **item** and not a **detail**, so **choose** the **name** of your **execution variable right**.

From this object item you should should whether call **item.getName()** or / and **item.getEducation()** if you haven't implemented or overriden a **public String toString()** method for your **Item** class or **@Override public String toString()** from the automatic inherited **java.lang.Object** class.

With that been said, let us fix and optimize your code:

---

**Main.java**

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Relying on the diamond operator
        List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
        Item item;
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Name plz?");
            String name = scan.nextLine();
            if (name.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }

            System.out.println("Education plz?");
            String education = scan.nextLine();
            if (education.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }

            item = new Item(name, education);
            if (!itemList.contains(item)) {
                itemList.add(item);
            }

        }

        System.out.println("Name & Education: ");
        for(Item item : itemList) {
            // Just call toString-method of Item class
            System.out.println(item.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

**Item.java**

```
package com.company;

public class Item {
    String name;
    String education;

    public Item(String name, String education) {
        this.name = name;
        this.education = education;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    
    public String getEducation() {
        return this.education;
    }
    // you could also add some setters for these attributes if you need some later on
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[Name: " + this.name + ", Education: " + this.education + "]";
    }
}
```

Hopefully, this will help you out. Also make sure you upvote the answer if it brings more details to you!

Comment: Make sure to update the answer if it helps!

Comment: How does this this contribute more than the accepted answer? The question was not about any ”optimizations”. Also where is the benchmark for these optimizations?

Comment: bringing more value is "subjective", stack overflow is not a forum. Its a Q&A site. People ask specific questions, and get specific answers. "Optimizations" in this provided answer are subjective, and also has nothing to do with the actual asked question.

Comment: Nope it,s also about about learning some concepts and why using those concepts. It,s not only about the solution that popup to you :).

Comment: Have you noticed that the number of viewers counts ? It,s also about how many people will get to this issue, and how many people will find solution their issues, not only the one who posted the issue. Let check the result in next 6 months :).